# Why CNAME record return 404 error on Azure DNS

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Last week I configure a DNS Zone on Azure to use it with an App Service.

I have an A Record (for @) with the IP of the App Service, a TXT Record (for @) with the azurewebsite domain (required by Azure to prove that I own the domain).

If I enter mydomain.com in the browser I can see my site, but if I enter www.mydomain.com I cant, so I added a CNAME for www pointed to mydomain.com, waited for the propagation but when I tried to enter I get an Azure error page:

[image]

Tried the flushdns but nothing happen.

If I check the propagation for mydomain.com shows the right IP of the app service, if I check the dns propagation of www.mydomain.com for CNAME shows mydomain.com and for A shows the IP of the app service: 
[image]

Anyone knows if I'm missing something? Here is my DNS Zone (with Ip's and domains removed).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just after posting the question I got the answer myself, what is missing is the Hostname in the App Service:

[image]

After added the www entry everything works fine with the DNS records described in the question.